# Unhandled Exception: Error on line 1, column 10: Invalid media type: expected "/". using flutter http

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, httprequest

I'm trying to send Http post request in my flutter application using [The flutter HTTP package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

Here is the code :

```dart
String url = 'http://my_website.com/api/panel/attendance/create';
Response response = await post(url, headers: {
  "Authorization": "Basic My_basic_auth",
  "content-type": "form-data",
}, body: {
  "username": username,
  "employee_id": employee_id,
  "latitude": latitude,
  "longitude": longitude,
  "type": type,
});
```

And am getting this strange error message :

`Unhandled Exception: Error on line 1, column 10: Invalid media type: expected "/".`

I think it is something with encoding or something, am not sure.

Comment: Have you created the http client with `var client = http.Client();` line ?

Comment: @MrLizzard it is not needed unless I am doing 2 requests from the same server, also .. I tried it but it gave the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling `client = https.client()` and using `client` for the call solved it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -

var response = await http.post(url, body);

Instead of Response response = await post(url, body);

If still not working give me some more data then I can solve the Error.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it still gives me the same error .. tell me what kind of info you need?